# Regex - match word or emoji from list - nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm working on a bot that has a match terms function. It's given text and terms list that it can match with (words/emojis). Here's my code that mostly works:

```
function matchTerms (terms, text) {
  //   > /(^|[^\w])/i.test('')
  //   < true
  //   > /(^|[^\w])/i.test('foo')
  //   < false
  //   > /(^|[^\w])/i.test('foo ')
  //   < true
  const matches = text.match(new RegExp(`(^|[^\\w])(${terms.join('|')})([^\\w]|$)`, 'i'))
  return matches ? matches[2] : null
}
```

This works. But my issue is if my matching term is an emoji and that emoji is attached to another word this regex won't find it. Anyone know a possible solution?

Comment: Your `[^\w]` requires that the preceding character be a non-word character (note that that simplifies to `\W`). If you want to permit word characters too, change that to `.`, or remove it entirely? Not really clear what you want the constraints on the match to be

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry if it was unclear. Essentially I want to pass a list ex. ['hi', ] and if my text contains either of those then it is true and returns which it found

Comment: So you just want to check whether the text *contains* either of those strings, no other conditions? Then remove the leading and trailing `[^\w]` parts, if you don't care whether the matched substring is next to another word character

Comment: Why can't you break it up, does a 1 liner help/disguise it ?

Answer (score 0):

How about as simple as this?

```js
console.log(//i.test('foo'))
```